# Taking guesses from a user with else if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

My program takes either 5, 10, 0r 20 guesses from the user. The user is supposed to guess a random number picked by the computer. The users guess should be between 1 and 100. If the user enters a guess over 100 or below 0, the program should ignore it and ask for that guess again. For example if the program asked "please enter guess #1" and the user entered 234, it would again say "please enter guess #1."

For some reason, my code is not doing so. If the user entered 234 for the first guess, it would move along to guess 2.
Can someone explain why my code isn't doing this?

Comment: If the entered number is out of range, remember to decrement `i` by 1, like this: `i--;`

Comment: I cannot edit but this question has wrong tag, it should be java, not javascript

Comment: @neoDev I edited the tag. Still under peer review

Comment: Oh now I understand why :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterator (in your case `int i`) increment by 1 for each iteration. You can decrement your iterator by 1 if the magic number is invalid.

```
if (guess > randomNumber && guess <= 100){
    System.out.println("Your guess, "+guess+", is greater than the magic number.");
    // If the value of i at this point is 1
    i--; //Decrement i by 1
    // Now the value of i is 0. The value of i in the next iteration will be 1
}
else if (guess < randomNumber && guess > 0){
    System.out.println("Your guess, "+guess+", is less than the magic number.");
    // If the value of i at this point is 1
    i--; //Decrement i by 1
    // Now the value of i is 0. The value of i in the next iteration will be 1
}
```